# freeing allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc, free

gcc 4.4.5 c89

I have a function called create_object where I allocate memory for a global structure. And I have a function called destroy_object where I check that the pointer is not null, then I free. Just incase I free memory that hasn't been allocated. However, I have tested this by making 2 consecutive calls to destroy_object. However, I get a stack dump on the second call. However, I am sure that it would not free as I have assigned the pointer to NULL. So it should skip the free function.

```
static struct Config_t {
    char protocol[LINE_SIZE];
    char mode[LINE_SIZE];
} *app_cfg = NULL;

int create_object()
{
    app_cfg = malloc(sizeof *app_cfg);
    memset(app_cfg, 0, sizeof *app_cfg);
}

void destroy_config()
{
    /* Check to see if the memory is ok to free */
    if(app_cfg != NULL) {
        free(app_cfg);
        app_cfg = NULL;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

================= EDIT ==========
Basicially I have in my main function a call to create_object() and I do some processing and then make a call to destory_object.

```
int main(void)
{
    create_object();

    /* Do some processing on the structure */

    destroy_object();

    return 0;
}
```

========================= Final Edit ====
static struct Config_t {
        char protocol[LINE_SIZE];
        char mode[LINE_SIZE];
    } app_cfg[1] {{"", ""}};

And now I am not using malloc and free.

Comment: That looks fine to me, can you post the code that uses this pointer and makes calls to `create_object` and `destroy_config`? Also, if you want to immediately initialize your memory allocated to `app_cfg` to 0s, you can combined your `malloc` and `memset` calls into one `calloc` call. Also, `free` on a null pointer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Passing a null pointer to `free()` is a safe no-op, so you don't need the null check in `destroy_config()`.

Comment: are you able to run the code through gdb and look at the backtrace after the SIGSEGV is raised?  Does it point to any other place in your program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only one suggestion. Don't allocate memory for this, it's a waste of effort.

Since `app_cfg` is a file-level variable, you can only have one copy at a time anyway, so there's little point in allocating and de-allocating it.

Just create it as a static *non-pointer* and use it:

```
static struct Config_t {
    char protocol[LINE_SIZE];
    char mode[LINE_SIZE];
} app_cfg;
```

You can still provide a `create` and `destroy` which `memset` the structure to zeros but even that may not be required:

```
void create_object (void) {
    memset(&app_cfg, 0, sizeof(app_cfg));
}

void destroy_config (void) {
    memset(&app_cfg, 0, sizeof(app_cfg));
}
```

Comment: `memset` definitely isn't needed.  It is guaranteed to be 0-filled, since it's static.  And destroy doesn't seem to make sense either.

Comment: @Matthew, I was thinking more of the case where you wanted it cleared before _reuse_ rather than initial use. But, even if it's _not_ cleared on create/destroy, decent coders shouldn't be writing code that's affected by values left lying around, hence my "may not be required" comment.

Comment: I have changed my source code and done as you suggested. Just one question. In my source code I will only need one copy of the struct variable (stack level, static global). I guess if I was creating many objects of this structure and wanted them to be available for the life-time of the application. I guess that is a good reason for using malloc?

Comment: you have a point about possible reuse (though I don't know that a method is needed).

Comment: @ant2009: yes. If you wanted multiple copies, you would them malloc them and return the pointer from `create_whatever`. It would then be useful to have a `destroy_whatever` to clean up since that means you would be able to change that code at will without affecting the API.

Answer (score 2):

using this code with gcc 3.3.3 under Cygwin works correctly for me when I call it twice.  You didn't tell us what you're doing outside of these functions, so look there first, e.g. maybe you're accidentally assigning a garbage non-NULL value to app_cfg between calls.  Also, if  you're not using a "big-name" compiler, there's a possibility this is a compiler bug (e.g. it may be overly optimistic at compile time and assume you'll never pass a NULL to destroy_config).  Try putting in something like:

```
void destroy_config()
{

    /* Check to see if the memory is ok to free */
    if(app_cfg != NULL) {
        printf("not null\n" );
        free(app_cfg);
        app_cfg = NULL;
    }else{
        printf("null\n" );
        }
}
```

to see if it really "knows" when it's null.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with freeing `NULL`, so that's not the source of the bug.  Also, it's almost certainly not a compiler bug.